# Widgets Twitter on my google site

Tags: twitter

Please, i have two questions: (i have added the widget twitter to my google site)

1- Is it possible to change the color theme (to a color other than the white and black) ? And How ?

2-I have added the frsilicon time line to my page as like here : [Any way to get widget-id for twitter widget from Twitter url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095320/any-way-to-get-widget-id-for-twitter-widget-from-twitter-url)
My question: is it possible to add more than one time line in the same widget ?
i'd like time lines of frsilicon and appleNews in the same widget..

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards.